Sequences based upon the Cantor space
Context/question: Considering the cantor space i.e. $2^\mathbb{N}$, what would be the elements $x$ in the Cantor space such that $\lim \frac{|\{m < n:x(m) = 1\}|}{n}$ does not converge?
My work: If $x$ has a finite amount of $1s$ or $0s$, then it is clear that it converges (applying monotone converge theorem). Another example would be $1010101010\ldots$ which converges to $1/2$.

Consider a sequence of $2^n$ $1$'s followed by $2^n$ $0$'s for every $n\ge 0$. It looks something like:
\begin{equation*}
101100111100001111111100000000\dots
\end{equation*}
Then, for $N = 2(2^0 + \dots + 2^n) + 2^{n + 1}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{|\{m\le N\colon x(m) = 1\}|}{N} = \frac{2^{n + 2} - 1}{2^{n + 2} + 2^{n + 1} - 2}\to\frac{2}{3}
\end{equation*}
as $n\to\infty$.
On the other hand, for $N = 2(2^0 + \dots + 2^n)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{|\{m\le N\colon x(m) = 1\}|}{N} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
for all positive integers $n$. Hence, the limit cannot exist.

thanks, makes sense. My real analysis a bit rusty lol
